# JSON response is not working in PHP version 5.3.24

Tags: java, php, json

I am developing a Java application where I have to pass values to my server and receive the response from PHP file **(version 5.3.24)**.The code is running fine in localhost and other live servers where the PHP version is greater than **5.3.24**.

This is my Java code.

```
public static void send() {

try {
// make json string, try also hamburger
String json = "{\"name\":\"Frank\",\"food\":\"pizza\",\"quantity\":3}";

// send as http get request
URL url = new URL("http://www.matjazcerkvenik.si/php/json/pizzaservice.php?order="+json);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

// Get the response
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(line);
}
rd.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
send();
}
```

This is my PHP code.

```
<?php
$order = $_GET["order"];
$obj = json_decode($order);
$name = $obj -> {"name"};
$food = $obj -> {"food"};
$quty = $obj -> {"quantity"};
if ($food == "pizza") {
$price = 4000;
} else if ($food == "hamburger") {
$price = 5000;
} else {
$price = 0;
}
$price = $price * $quty;
if ($price == 0) {
$status = "not-accepted";
} else {
$status = "accepted";
}
$array = array("name" => $name, "food" => $food, "quantity" => $quty, "price" => $price, "status"     
=> $status);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: Please provide any output/log/error from php. Check /var/log/php-errors.log

Comment: It returns null from php to java

Comment: Output: {"name":null,"food":null,"quantity":null,"price":0,"status":"not-accepted"}

Comment: Thank you. Can you please debug your php script with some extra information? For example change it a bit: <?php
$order = $_GET["order"]; var_dump($order);
$obj = json_decode($order); ...

Comment: Output : string(58) "{\"name\":\"Frank\",\"food\":\"hamburger\",\"quantity\":3}" {"name":null,"food":null,"quantity":null,"price":0,"status":"not-accepted"}

Comment: Got it. Looks like your php version do not stripslashes from json. Will answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your php script a bit:

```
<?php
$order = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($_GET["order"]) : $_GET["order"];
$obj = json_decode($order);
$name = $obj -> {"name"};
$food = $obj -> {"food"};
$quty = $obj -> {"quantity"};
if ($food == "pizza") {
$price = 4000;
} else if ($food == "hamburger") {
$price = 5000;
} else {
$price = 0;
}
$price = $price * $quty;
if ($price == 0) {
$status = "not-accepted";
} else {
$status = "accepted";
}
$array = array("name" => $name, "food" => $food, "quantity" => $quty, "price" => $price, "status"     
=> $status);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: Log says: Call to undefined function stripslashes().

Comment: That's something new to me - stripslashes is standard php function. Did you copypaste this line from my answer?